# Ordering Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want ordering this array.

```
var array = [
    { number : 10, Title : "Some"},
    { number : 13, Title : "blob"},
    { number : 50, Title : "hh"},
    { number : 8, Title : "dd"},
    { number : 5, Title : "b"},
    { number : 125, Title : "oh"},
    { number : 16, Title : "so"},
    { number : 62, Title : "what"},
    { number : 921, Title : "aa"},
    { number : 1, Title : "hmm"}
];
```

I want ordering by 'Number' (asc or desc).
But, I don't know how to ordering this array, because of 'Title'.

How can I ordering?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the `sort` function on the Array prototype.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9gj9on3v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's Array objects have a `sort` function that receives a compare function (callback) that compares 2 values manually. Use them to compare whatever property you want.

```js
var array = [
    { number : 10, Title : "Some"},
    { number : 13, Title : "blob"},
    { number : 50, Title : "hh"},
    { number : 8, Title : "dd"},
    { number : 5, Title : "b"},
    { number : 125, Title : "oh"},
    { number : 16, Title : "so"},
    { number : 62, Title : "what"},
    { number : 921, Title : "aa"},
    { number : 1, Title : "hmm"}
];

array.sort(function (a, b) { return a.number > b.number });
alert(JSON.stringify(array, null, ' '));
```

Comment: You don't need `sorted` array, `sort` works inline on the array